# Enable and disable cellular data option through code in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Is there is any option so that i can enable and disable cellular data using app.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API available to control cellular data within in an app , User should go to settings to enable or disable cellular data.

Comment: Ok.can we track whether cellular data is enabled or not.

Comment: Starting in iOS 8 you can at least send the user to the setting for your app. But also there will be no way flipping the switch by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apple's [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) to determine if you are using cellular or Wifi and choose to send network requests or not according to the cellular availability.

Comment: i know how to use reachability code to check internet connection.Can you provide more code apart from this.